# Assign input from one array to two/several others

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to retrieve array-input based on array positions.

Specifically I want a line of text to be broken when it reaches a certain length, and "feed line - vbLF" at certain delimiters and not just at a certain length, destroying the word.

This is my attempt, but I would like the code to be written in the form furthest below:

```vb
If Len(strListOfNames) > 36 Then

    arrstrSplit = Split(strListOfNames, ",") 'delimiter could have been "space" = " " too for general text and not lists
    For arrElmntNum = 0 To UBound(arrstrSplit)
        intLenStrName = Len(arrstrSplit(arrElmntNum))
        If (intLenStrNamesPlural + intLenStrName) < 36 Then
            intLenStrNamesPlural = intLenStrNamesPlural + intLenStrName
            arrFrstNamesPlural.Add (arrstrSplit(arrElmntNum))
        Else
            ReDim arrFrstNamesPlural(0 To arrElmntNum - 1)
        
            ReDim arrScndNamesPlural(0 To (UBound(arrstrSplit) - arrElmntNum))
        
            For FrstArrElmntNum = 0 To (arrElmntNum - 1)
                arrFrstNamesPlural(FrstArrElmntNum) = arrstrSplit(FrstArrElmntNum)
                strFrstNamesPlural = Join(arrFrstNamesPlural, ", ")
            Next
        
            For ScndArrElmntNum = arrElmntNum To UBound(arrstrSplit)
                arrScndNamesPlural(ScndArrElmntNum - arrElmntNum) = arrstrSplit(ScndArrElmntNum)
                arrScndNamesPlural = Join(arrScndNamesPlural, ", "):
            Next

        End If
    Next
End If
```

My intention - and hopefully best solution:

```vb
If Len(strListOfNames) > 36 Then

    arrstrSplit = Split(strListOfNames, ",")
    For arrElmntNum = 0 To UBound(arrstrSplit)
        intLenStrName = Len(arrstrSplit(arrElmntNum))
        If (intLenStrNamesPlural + intLenStrName) < 36 Then
            intLenStrNamesPlural = intLenStrNamesPlural + intLenStrName
        Else
            arrFrstBorholesStr(0 to (arrElmntNum-1)) = arrstrSplit(0 to (arrElmntNum-1))
            arrFrstBorholesStr(0 to (UBound(arrstrSplit) - arrElmntNum) = arrstrSplit(arrElmntNum to UBound(arrstrSplit))
            GoTo SplitIsDone_CheckIsComplete
        End If
    Next
End If

SplitIsDone_CheckIsComplete:  'Jumps out of the for-loop.
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your requirement. Can you provide a sample of the input text, along with a description of how you'd want it broken up?

Comment: 2023_2,  2023_8,  2023_10,  2023_15,  NGT_5,  NC6_12,  L9_1,  L6_1,  2023_13,  2023_14, broken as in \\ 2023_2,  2023_8,  2023_10,  2023_15,  NGT_5,  NC6_12,  L9_1,  L6_1, \\ 2023_13,  2023_14 Sorry, but can't write "enter in this comment" And thank you for improving the question readability

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but the following code will accept a string and split it into an array based on the input_delimiter you specify. It will then build an array of strings, combining elements from the first array up to the specified max_line_length.  Elements in the output_array are separated by the output_delimiter specified.

The following list:

Albania,Andorra,Austria,Belarus,Belgium,Bosnia and Herzegovina,Bulgaria,Croatia,Czechia,Denmark,Estonia,Finland,France,Germany,Greece,Holy See,Hungary,Iceland,Ireland,Italy,Latvia,Liechtenstein,Lithuania,Luxembourg,Malta,Moldova,Monaco,Montenegro,Netherlands,North Macedonia,Norway,Poland,Portugal,Romania,Russia,San Marino,Serbia,Slovakia,Slovenia,Spain,Sweden,Switzerland,Ukraine,United Kingdom

Can be converted into an array of:

```
Albania-Andorra-Austria-Belarus-Belgium
Bosnia and Herzegovina-Bulgaria-Croatia-Czechia
Denmark-Estonia-Finland-France-Germany-Greece
Holy See-Hungary-Iceland-Ireland-Italy-Latvia
Liechtenstein-Lithuania-Luxembourg-Malta-Moldova
Monaco-Montenegro-Netherlands-North Macedonia
Norway-Poland-Portugal-Romania-Russia-San Marino
Serbia-Slovakia-Slovenia-Spain-Sweden-Switzerland
Ukraine-United Kingdom
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub test_array()
  Dim x As Long
  Dim new_array() As String
  Const text = "Albania,Andorra,Austria,Belarus,Belgium,Bosnia and Herzegovina,Bulgaria,Croatia,Czechia,Denmark,Estonia,Finland,France,Germany,Greece,Holy See,Hungary,Iceland,Ireland,Italy,Latvia,Liechtenstein,Lithuania,Luxembourg,Malta,Moldova,Monaco,Montenegro,Netherlands,North Macedonia,Norway,Poland,Portugal,Romania,Russia,San Marino,Serbia,Slovakia,Slovenia,Spain,Sweden,Switzerland,Ukraine,United Kingdom"
  new_array = array_organizer(text, 50, ",", "-")
  For x = LBound(new_array) To UBound(new_array)
    Debug.Print new_array(x)
  Next
End Sub


Function array_organizer(text As String, max_line_length As Long, Optional input_delimiter As String = "", Optional output_delimiter As String = "")
    Dim one_line As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim output_collection As New Collection
    Dim output_array() As String
    Dim items() As String
    items = Split(text, input_delimiter)
    
    For x = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
      one_line = items(x)
      
      ' key trying to add the next item to the current line as long as we have items
      Do Until x + 1 > UBound(items)

           ' check to see if there is room on the current line to add the next item, if not we exit loop
           If Len(one_line) + Len(items(x + 1)) + Len(output_delimiter) > max_line_length Then Exit Do
           
           ' if we made it here, there is room to add the next item to the current line
           'add the next item to the current line including an output delimiter
           one_line = one_line & output_delimiter & items(x + 1)
            x = x + 1 ' move to the next item
           
           DoEvents 'this will allows us to interrupt the code if a bug puts us into an endless loop
      Loop
      
      'were are done building the current line, add it to the output colllection
      output_collection.Add one_line
      
    Next
    
    ' the requirements are to return an array, so will size the array then copy the collection to the array
    ReDim output_array(0 To output_collection.Count - 1)
    For x = 1 To output_collection.Count
      output_array(x - 1) = output_collection(x)
    Next
    array_organizer = output_array
    
    ' if the we are allowed to retrun a collection instead of an array, delete the prior block and enable this line
    'array_organizer = output_collection

End Function
```

In the "organize_array" function, I use a collection to accumulate lines instead of re-dimming the output_array for each new line because re-dimming arrays is really inefficient

Comment: Thank you!  I will have to look at it for when I have time (because I will need some here it seems, - I am not familiar with "collections"). If it is true that collections work well for lists, but don't have the same troubles as with arrays, then I guess that is something I should learn. Do you have any special recommendations to start-tutorials?

Comment: I talk about them in the class I teach at university.  go to time index 51:35 in this video and you'll see a straightforward example.  https://vba-course.blogspot.com/2023/01/excels-built-in-file-dialogs.html

Comment: This  looks like a pretty good site that talks directly about collections.  Remember that Excel has built-in collections (like the collection of all worksheets in a workbook) in addition to collections you can build yourself.  It starts talking about making your own collections about 1/4 of the way in.  https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/